# Verbs without pronouns

Tags: verbs, pronouns, ellipsis

- > You're going to yell at my son, and **you expect** me to just stand and watch?
- > You're going to yell at my son and **expect** me to stand there and watch?

In the second sentence there is no pronoun preceding **expect**, is it still grammatically correct?
Can you provide a link where I can look into this?

Comment: Yes, it's fine. The clause contains a coordination of verb phrases: "You're going to [yell at my son] and [expect me to [stand there] [and watch]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both correct. We often drop the second subject pronoun in such structures. There is a subtle difference to my ears though.

> You're going to yell at my son, and you expect me to just stand and watch

In this case the comma after son invites me to pause and then when I carry on my tone of voice would change into one of disbelief. I might carry on by saying *You cannot be serious* or something similar.

> You're going to yell at my son and expect me to stand there and watch?

In this case I would read straight through and so the whole sentence would seem more neutral, I would just be reporting the facts of the situation.

I would therefore prefer the first one in this example but either is correct.